# Odd behaviour in Firefox 8 with fixed positioned navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have the following page I'm working on: http://jeunespoir.org/demo/.

The top nav menu has a child anchor which holds the left logo image. The navigation is fixed in position and the logo is absolute positionned. When the user scrolls past a certain point in the page, the logo will hide itself while the navigation remains visible. In chrome, there is no problem, but with Firefox 8 there seems to be a spacing between the navigation and the top and left of the document that is added (about 1px).

What strikes me as really odd is that this spacing isn't uniform accross the top of the navigation, it seems to only be near the placement of where the logo displays and hides. Very odd.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem in FireFox. You did a very nice job on it from my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i feel your

```
 <ul class="main-nav">

 <ul class="drop">
```

class styles are overlapping, need to fine tune.

Comment: Fixing the overlap (caused by a padding-top. replaced it with a margin-top) seemed to fix the visual glitch i was experiencing.